# how to use AsyncTask in Class A and make it pop dialog on Class B

Tags: android, android-asynctask

wrote an AsyncTask in its own class.
Calling it from class B.
and I want it to show something in class A which is the current running `Activity`.
Should I use `runOnUiThread()`? or do I somehow  `setOwnerActivity(Activity)`?
I am clueless as to what is going wrong..

this is the task:

```
public class popTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Context con;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(con);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("New & Hot advertise");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yoda);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public popTask(Context con){
        this.con=con;
    }
}
```

Comment: this may be the same code but it is a totally diff question....

Comment: Agreed it's not a duplicate, but you could do some work on the quality and presentation of the question.

Comment: i'm very new to stackflow as is probably evident. doing my best to learn how to best pose a question :_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a constructor for this Async task which had a reference to Activity A.

For example:

```
public popTask(ClassA ref) {
    super();
    this.ref = ref;
    // do stuff
}
```

Then, using this reference to your Activity, you can call an activity's method. If you want to show something, this calling always must be done in onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute (**Never on doInBackground**).

Hope it helps!